# Get datas from BLE device directly to Apple Watch

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I have been researching since last 2 days. I have an iOS app and watch kit extension. In iOS app I have included CBCentralManager and connected to Peripheral. Everything is working fine in case if the iOS app running parallel to the apple watchkit app. Even though my iOS app not running I want to communicate to BLE Peripheral device. Is it possible ??. Please let me know. Any ideas/suggestions could be very helpful. Thank you for spending your valuable time.

Comment: Possible solution is : You need to connect BLE device with your iOS app & Then communicate your app with Watchkit.